# Responsive background css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to make my background image responsive. The background is responsive till it reaches a smaller screen size. When the browser width changes to about 600px, some empty space on the right appears beside the image. But, above 600px, the background image resizes properly with the browser width. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? The `izonebg` image in the `group` div is causing the problem

Here's an image:

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
}


header{
    padding: 2em 2em;
    margin: -1em 0;
}

.logo{
    background: url('izonebg.jpg') no-repeat left;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 65px;
 
}

@media (min-width: 675px){
    .logo{
        width: 500px;
        height: 108px;
    }
}

.groupbg{
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#aboutiz{
    font-family: Kiona;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content-wrapper{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#about-content{
    font-family: Acid;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 1.15em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    
}

@media (min-width: 860px){
    .content-flex{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    #aboutiz{
        font-size: 3.7em;
    }
    
    #about-content{
        font-size: 1.75em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
}

.info{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div class = "container">
        <main role = "main">
            <div class = "group">
                <img src = "izonebg.jpg" alt = "group" class = "groupbg">
            </div>
            
            <div class = "content-wrapper content-flex">
                <div class = "about">
                    <p id = "aboutiz">ABOUT IZ*ONE</p>
                </div>
            
                <div class = "info">
                    <p id = "about-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie ipsum at mi tincidunt, ac bibendum tortor rutrum. Morbi arcu tortor, pretium quis auctor sed, maximus eu lectus. Vestibulum eu consequat metus. Vivamus eu turpis eu enim aliquet sagittis. Mauris non malesuada felis. Quisque lacinia luctus sagittis. Integer eu ultrices dolor. In est sapien, eleifend nec lorem in, ultricies malesuada lacus. Sed non nunc eu turpis ultrices dapibus vitae nec ligula. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior if you don't provide the image

Comment: Which image is giving problems (the CSS background one - logo - or the div which has a bg class)? I cannot reproduce the problem whatever aspect ratio images I use so I think  you'll have to put up a working snippet with the actual image so we can try it.

Comment: @Spectric I'll edit the question and provide the image

Comment: @AHaworth The `izonebg` image in the `group` div is causing a problem. I added the image now. Should I provide the code snippet too?

Comment: Yes please provide a working snippet which we can run as I can't reproduce the problem with your image and the code currently in the question.

Comment: @AHaworth I provided the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `width: 400px` to `width:100%` and add one more property `max-width:400px` in **`.logo`**.
You can follow below snippet, I hope this snippet will help you a lot.

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}    
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
header{
    padding: 2em 2em;
    margin: -1em 0;
}
.logo{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBunR.jpg') no-repeat left;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 65px;
}
@media (min-width: 675px){
    .logo{
        width: 500px;
        height: 108px;
    }
}
.groupbg{
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#aboutiz{
    font-family: Kiona;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.content-wrapper{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#about-content{
    font-family: Acid;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 1.15em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
@media (min-width: 860px){
    .content-flex{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #aboutiz{
        font-size: 3.7em;
    }
    #about-content{
        font-size: 1.75em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
}
.info{
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <main role="main">
        <div class="group">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBunR.jpg" alt="group" class="groupbg">
        </div>

        <div class="content-wrapper content-flex">
            <div class="about">
                <p id="aboutiz">ABOUT IZ*ONE</p>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <p id="about-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie ipsum at mi tincidunt, ac bibendum tortor rutrum. Morbi arcu tortor, pretium quis auctor sed, maximus eu lectus. Vestibulum eu consequat metus. Vivamus eu turpis eu enim aliquet sagittis. Mauris non malesuada felis. Quisque lacinia luctus sagittis. Integer eu ultrices dolor. In est sapien, eleifend nec lorem in, ultricies malesuada lacus. Sed non nunc eu turpis ultrices dapibus vitae nec ligula.
                 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem was with the background image in the `group` div. This weird thing is, the background image is responsive when I run the code snippet here, but when I run my file, the image is not responsive :// I did the exact same thing as you but it's not responsive

Comment: @Nasheetat You may need to check override style through `Inspect Element` method on your `browser`. May be some style written in you existing style file for `.group` div.